# How can I develop O365 Active Directory login Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft365

How can I develop O365 Active Directory login Android? I tried Azure Active Directory, After I put Username and Password I'm getting like this **aadsts50011 the reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application** Please Help me to Find out the issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi,  Has your problem been solved?

Comment: yes, its solved, I was put Redirector URL, I put Correct one, its working Fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a general solution to the problem of **not match**:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with `http`, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.