# AADSTS50011 after creating CNAME

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect

I had my IdenityServer4 oidc service running correctly as an AppService on Azure. Now I created a DNS entry in my hosting to create better names for all the services. For Azure-AD I keep getting this error:

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '<my app id>'.
```

I have these two reply-urls setup in Azure AD portal:

```
https://account.mysite.com/signin-microsoft
https://myapp-oidc.azurewebsites.net/signin-microsoft
```

The second one works but the first does not, giving the error. Is there any way for me to debug this and see what reply url apparently is different that the one configured?

Here's the setup in startup.cs:

```
 services
   .AddAuthentication()
   .AddMicrosoftAccount("Microsoft", options => {
      options.SignInScheme = "Identity.External";
      options.ClientId = "xxx";
      options.ClientSecret = "xxx";
   })
```

I did the same for google (https://account.mysite.com/signin-google) and that worked right away but I can't get Azure to work on the new address.

Comment: I have answered similar questions before： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839985/how-can-i-develop-o365-active-directory-login-android/66842398#66842398

Comment: I got them out of the urls for both addresses but they appear to be the same (just both url encoded)

Comment: Can you share the code where you configure the reply url `https://account.mysite.com/signin-microsoft`?

Comment: That url is added automatically through services/ middelware. The code I use to add the microsoft account to the services is already there, how that is added to the routing table i'm not sure, one of these lines: 
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("AllowCORS");
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });

Comment: Thing is it works if I call the oidc service with the AppService address. For Google I added the second reply-url and it worked sraight away but Microsoft account does not for the dns entry..